# What must I do with C++ libraries on cross compilation?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

Here is my compiler part of my config:

```
IF(UNIX)
    ## Compiler flags

    # specify the cross compiler
    SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /home/username/projects/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/username/projects/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-g++)

    if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3")
        set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lsqlite3 -lrt -lpthread")
    endif()

    target_link_libraries(complex
      ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
ENDIF(UNIX)
```

There are 3 problems : -lsqlite3 -lrt -lpthread

How must I to make them for my architecture and specify here? How to set (using set?) the path of compiled libraries after I will get them recompiled for my architecture somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do cross-compilation with CMake you really should use a toolchain file for that. See the [CMake Wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling) for an introduction. In order to use third-party libraries (i.e. not included by the cross-compilation toolchain) you need to cross-compile them too.

**Edit**: Since you are using the buildroot toolchain, you can use the already included CMake toolchain file. Just pass `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/username/projects/buildroot/output/toolchainfile.cmake` when invoking CMake. No need to set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in your `CMakeLists.txt` file. Also, setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is considered to be very bad practice.

Presumably you have built sqlite3 while building the buildroot toolchain, so you can use it just like any other library. I.e:

```cmake
find_path(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR sqlite3.h)
find_library(SQLITE3_LIBRARY sqlite3)
if(NOT SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find sqlite3.h")
endif()
if(NOT SQLITE3_LIBRARY)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find the sqlite3 library")
endif()

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

# ...

target_link_libraries(complex
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY}
  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
  rt)
```

Lastly, do not set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to `-O3`. The user should pass `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` when configuring the project instead.

Comment: I'm using buildroot toolchain

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to cross-compile the dependencies as well. The path depends on where you install them.

Btw., using `-lpthread` is not the safe way of getting POSIX threads. You should give the option `-pthread` to both the compiler and the linker.